# SSLParameters in jax-rs client

Tags: java, rest, security, ssl, jax-rs

I would like to know how can I set custom SSLParameters (as in modifying ciphersuites) in JAX-RS on the client-side.
I have already tried changing the HTTPS Configuration like you do on the server-side but I can't seem to find how to do it...
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to do HTTPS with jax-rs client?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: Are you using Jersey as a JAX-RS Client? In this case you can have a look at `SslConfigurator` from Jersey API.